# How to specify libcurl SFTP hmac option

Tags: linux, windows, curl, sftp, libcurl

I have a version of libcurl compiled with libssh2 (fairly recent versions, OpenSSL v1.0.2 and libssh2 v1.4.3) so it supports uploading/downloading files with sftp. I have limited experience with ssh and sftp but I know that on Linux there are additional options that can be specified with the sftp command such as the MAC (Message Authentication Code). To do a simple connect you can do something like this:

```
sftp -oCiphers=... -oMACs=... myuser@myhost
```

The above command works. [Here is one reference I found.](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm) However, now I need to do the same thing using libcurl so I can test on Windows. I need to test different cipher/MAC combinations, for example **3des-cbc** or **aes128-cbc** ciphers with **hmac-md5** or **hmac-sha1**.

Does libcurl with sftp support specifying the hmac option? And if so how do I tell it which to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got on the libcurl and libssh2 mailing lists and asked the question and was told that the option I am looking for does not exist in libssh2 and therefore does not exist in libcurl. Basically libssh2 is compiled to support particular hmac ciphers (like MD5 or SHA1). So, compiling different versions of my libssh2 library targeted for a specific hmac cipher looks like the only way to do what I need to do.